# How to watch nested Vuex store values

Tags: vue.js, vuex, watch, computed-properties

I have a Vue project where I need to watch some Vuex store values. Here is the code:

```
computed: {
    serverCategories: {
        get() {
            return this.$store.state[this.storeName].serverFilters.categories[0].value.name;
        },
        set(value) {
            return value;
        },
    }
},
watch: {
    serverCategories: {
        deep: true,
        handler(newVal, OldVal) {
            console.log(newVal);
        }
    }
},
```

But it does not react on changes. serverCategories still contains the same value although the value in store state is changed. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vuex  `mapGetters` which you can wrap in your computed properties (see [documentation here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper))

I would highly recommand using getters each time you need to access the store instead of `$store.state.myStore.myValue`.

You can also use vuex to mutate your data (through `mutations` and the vuex function `mapMutations` or though `actions` using `mapActions`)
Example :

### store

```js
getters: {
  myValue: (state) => state.myValue
}
```

### Vue component

```js
<template>
   <p> {{ myValueFromGetter }}</p>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
   computed: {
   ...mapGetters({
      myValueFromGetter: 'myGetter/myValue'
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to try it. What is the difference between getter and state watching? Does it work with nested values?

Comment: If you  just need to get your data you can use the `mapState`. You should use getters if you need to filter the data for example instead of filtering it in the script part.